# Solving for x with square root

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to solve a problem and right now I'm stuck with something that looks like this:

$ax^2 + bx + \sqrt{cx} = 0$

And i have absolutely no clue as what to do with this. Any help would be apreciated, thank you

Comment: Set $u=\sqrt x$. Its splits into $u(au^3+bu+\sqrt c)=0$. The rest depends on the values of the coefficients.

Comment: Have you tried moving the radical term to the other side and then squaring both sides?

Comment: @Bernard But how do I solve for x from there on? Im sorry, I'm in the tenth grade and I don't know how to get x with a power of 3

Comment: Check Cardan's Theorem for cubic equations.

Comment: $x=0$ is a solution.

Comment: Do you really have letters $a, b, c$? Solving cubic equations is doable, but not quite trivial. Cardano's method/formulae work well if there is only one real root (which is the case here if $4b^3+27ac>0$), and you have to use trigonometric methods if there are $3$ realroots (case $4b^3+27ac<0$). Unless $a,b,c$ have specific values…

Comment: @Bernard Worse, I have a that $a = (-1 - \frac{mA}{mB})$ , $b = x0$ and $c = \sqrt{GmB}$

Comment: It comes from a physics problem?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, and I've solved it so far to that, but I can't figure a way out

Comment: I don't see either. Check your calculations. Are you sure you used the good variables or parameters?

Comment: @Bernard This is one of the possibilities, because this is a system and c comes from a quadratic expression meaning it can be positive or negative and here im testing the positive solution out, altough it being negative only makes a and b positiive, nothing else